# AngularJS slash after hashbang gets encoded

Tags: angularjs

I've configured AngularJS locationProvider to use html5 (and fallbacks in hashbangs)

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!')
```

The problem is that if I access for instance `http://locahost/#!/pathh/subpath` angular ends up rewriting the URL shown in the browser as `http://locahost/#!%2Fpath%2Fsubpath`. I'm using chrome 27 on mac.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the problem? Is routing not working properly?

Answer (score 2):

This may help: [angular-slash-gets-encoded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19741919/angular-slash-gets-encoded)

I solved it by doing two things:

1. I added `<base href="/">` to index.html.
2. I activated HTML5 mode but without prefix.

This way I can use either `http://localhost/#!/route` or `http://localhost/route` and the URL gets rewritten correctly.

Comment: There is sort of a step 3 missing, which is that your `<a>` tags should no longer be `href="#/route"` but `href="route"`