# prevent angular change hashtag and slash in URL

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome-extension, gmail

I try to stop angular to modify the URL format
like from `'mail.google.com/#inbox'`

to `'mail.google.com/#/inbox'`

the context is I'm developing a Chrome extension, and customer like to use it with Streak in the same time. But sometimes my app will stop 'pipeline' feature of Streak shows up.

And the reason I guess is angular change the URL to different format therefore, stop some function of Streak(maybe)

so, to prevent angular add slash after hash tag,
I use html4 mode in config like

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

in fact, it works! but with error message:

```
$location in HTML5 mode requires a tag to be present!
```

so I change it the config part to

```
 $locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled: true,
        requireBase: true
       });
```

then error message disappear, but slash will be encode
ex:

```
"mail.google.com/#pipeline/aaabbbccc..."
```

become

```
"mail.google.com/#pipeline%2Faaabbbccc..."
```

and pipeline not shows up.

then I find method to prevent slash encode from [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19741919/angular-slash-gets-encoded)

I change config back to

```
 $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

and add  tag to head to index;
as I'm developing a inject script app
I add the html tag by Jquery in content script

```
$('head').append('<base href="/">');
```

then situation become weird,it will open new tab and sometimes sign me out of gmail, also pipeline not shows as well.

Furthermore, I find the thing trigger URL change is some directive use $state

Is somebody have idea how to prevent angular modify URL formate change?
or my assumption of reason is wrong?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$location/nobase check this following will be help you and check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19741919/angular-slash-gets-encoded

Comment: thanks for your comment, I tried these method.
While I enable html5mode, and add <base href='/'>
when I click pipeline feature, it open new tab(well with correct link address, but will switch to default gmail link few seconds late).
I decide to send this issue to Streak, I can not handle its reaction.